# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) on project control

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies, sts

I'm using java 8 and STS for my project, but when trying maven clean it gives me the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) on project control: Failed to clean project

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <groupId>com.ndp</groupId>
    <artifactId>control</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>control</name>

    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Boot Starter for JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Oracle JDBC Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HikariCP Connection Pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I tried to add

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</plugin>
```

but nothing worked, I also tried to add

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

It also didn't work

Comment: check whether there is simply a file or directory inside your target folder which cannot  be deleted. Otherwise try to remove your dependencies and plugins. mvn clean should work, even if compile  does not. Then one by one add them again.

Comment: can you provide output of: `mvn -e clean`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a **UTF-8** error and your maven-resources-plugin have no of vulnerabilities.

add this into your properties file

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

it is worked for me, may be you will